# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los registros ordenados por fecha, última semana, último mes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Muy buenas, En una tabla tengo guardados unos registros y me gustaría mostrar como dice el título, mostrar última semana, último mes.

La fecha que almaceno en mi tabla queda con el siguiente formato "2020-08-21" por ejemplo.
Sé ordenar todos los registros por la consulta con "ORDER BY fecha DESC" pero no sé cómo realizar para obtener solo los datos de la última semana, o el último mes, independientemente del día en el que esté.

Desconozco si se tiene que hacer en la misma consulta o si tengo que usar php para calcular la fecha y luego ponerlos en la consulta.

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Sería más fácil tratar de ayudarte si proporcionas la estructura de tu tabla y cómo estás intentando hacer las consultas. Saludos!

Comment: `con el siguiente formato "2020-08-21"...` -- el tipo de dato `DATE` no tiene formato. Ahora bien, si estás usando un `VARCHAR` para almacenar fechas, eso te generará muchos problemas en el futuro; suguiero convertirlo en `DATE` a la brevedad.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar con algo como lo siguiente, aclaro que desconozco la estructura de tu tabla , lo hice con datos genericos. Obviamente deberias adaptarlo a. tu estructura de DB.

La funcion CURDATE() devuelve la fecha actual.
La función DATE_SUB () resta un intervalo de hora / fecha de una fecha y luego devuelve la fecha.

Para mostrar los de la ultima semana podria ser asi:

```
SELECT NumFactura, Fecha, idCliente, idEmpleado FROM factura WHERE fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND curdate();
```

Para obtener lo del mes anterior seria asi:

```
SELECT NumFactura, Fecha, idCliente, idEmpleado FROM factura WHERE fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND curdate();
```

Fuente: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f21/mostrar-registros-ultima-semana-mes-805708/

Comment: Pero me vale para el modelo de Date que estoy guardando en la bbdd ?? o tiene que tener otro formato en vez del "2020-08-21" por ejemplo

Comment: En la pagina donde explica la funcion Date_sub hay un ejemplo con la fecha en ese formato por lo que calculo te va a funcionar, tendrias que probarlo. El ejemplo es el siguiente: SELECT DATE_SUB("2017-06-15", INTERVAL 10 DAY);

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionó @franco fernandez, puedes usar `INTERVAL` para establecer el rango de tolerancia. Y como lo que deseas es obtener todos los registros A PARTIR de una fecha mínima, yo haría algo así, para evitar usar `BETWEEN`:

```sql
SELECT
  a,
  b,
  c
FROM
  tabla
WHERE
  fecha >= DATE_SUB(
    CURDATE(),
    INTERVAL 1 WEEK -- o "1 MONTH"
  );
```

Comment: He probado a añadir registros en días anteriores que deberían mostrarse en la ultima semana, pero no muestra ningún registro. Tiene algo que ver la forma en que se guarda la fecha en mi bbdd ? El formato que guarda es un string así "2020-08-21"

Comment: Pues no, ese es el formato correcto: YYYY-MM-DD.
Ya intentaste retornar todo sin ese filtro y ver si realmente se guardaron los registros que dices que agregaste, y si tienen las fechas que les pusiste?
También puede que la fecha en donde ejecutas MySQL esté incorrecta, prueba dar un SELECT CURDATE(); para verificar eso.